# How to i chain two parts of an animation together in jetpack compose so the the offset increases then decreases?

Tags: kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, jetpack-compose-animation

Ive recently got into doing animations using jet pack compose and am wondering how you can make it so that when you increase a value in an offset, once the animation reaches that value it then changes the value to another value. So like update transition but instead of at the same time, one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to use Kotlin coroutines. I managed to get it working fine. You have to use coroutines in order to launch the animations in the correct sequence like this:

```kotlin
animationRoutine.launch {
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            animate(
                startingValue,
                targetValue,
                animationSpec = whatYouWant,
                block = { value, _ -> whateverYouNeed = value }
            )
        }
        launch {
            animate(
                initialValue,
                targetValue,
                animationSpec = whatYouWant,
                block = { value, _ -> whateverYouNeed = value }
            )
        }
}
```

Each of launch scope launches everything in a non blocking way if you tell it to allowing you to run multiple animations at once at a lower level and to sequence the animations you add another coroutine for the next part of the animation.

Answer (score 6):

Actually @RaBaKa's answer is partially correct, but it's missing information about how the animation should be run.

It should be done as a side effect. For example, you can use `LaunchedEffect`: it is already running in a coroutine scope. It is perfectly normal to run one animation after another - as soon as the first suspend function finishes, the second will be started:

```
val value = remember { Animatable(0f) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    value.animateTo(
        20f,
        animationSpec = tween(2000),
    )
    value.animateTo(
        10f,
        animationSpec = tween(2000),
    )
}
Text(value.value.toString())
```

If you want to do this in response to some action, such as pressing a button, you need to run the coroutine yourself. The main thing is to run the animations in the same coroutine so that they are chained.

```
val value = remember { Animatable(0f) }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Button(onClick = {
    scope.launch {
        value.animateTo(
            20f,
            animationSpec = tween(2000),
        )
        value.animateTo(
            10f,
            animationSpec = tween(2000),
        )
    }
}) {
    
}
Text(value.value.toString())
```

Comment: yeah the looks similar to what i did to get it working except i used the animate function

Comment: how would you set up cancellation of such an animation? For example, clicking on the button cancels the current animation and starts a new one?

Comment: @Mark `scope.launch` returns `Job` object - you can store and cancel it.

Comment: @PhilDukhov thanks though I ended up controlling it by using an appropriate key in the `LaunchedEffect`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Animatable`

```
val value = remember { Animatable(0f) }    //Initial Value
```

Then in compose you can just use

```
value.animateTo(20f)
```

then

```
value.animateTo(10f)
```

For more information visit the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatable)

Comment: From what Ive found i think i might have to sequence the animation using coroutines, Im going to give it a go and see, i don't think you can do what you said, won't it just cancel the first animation immediately?

Comment: Yeah, it'll cancel  if there is an animation running, have you tried keyframes?, does that help you??

Comment: I managed to get it working with coroutines, you can see my answer provided if it interests you thanks :D